# Making a countdown based on MySQL

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, date-formatting

The software I use logs what time a song is played in a database with a timestamp formatted like `2011-04-13 17:55:46`. It also logs the length of the song in milliseconds. How can I get that timestamp converted to milliseconds? Secondly, how can I calculate the time remaining so I could use it to cause the page to refresh when time is up?

Comment: Seems like a duplicate of [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5657151/countdown-based-on-mysql-entry]

Comment: Why don't you just store the timestamp in millisecond?

Comment: The duplicate question did not really get an answer, maybe Austin decided to re-ask the question under a different account?

Comment: You want this in Javascript right?

Comment: I couldn't get access to my other account. Yes, javascript would be fine.

Answer (score 0):

## Code:

```
var date = new Date("2011-04-13 17:55:46");
var milliseconds = date.getTime(); 
alert (milliseconds);
```

## Output:

```
1302697546000
```

## For date difference, many duplicate posts:

[How to calculate date difference in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7763327/how-to-calculate-date-difference-in-javascript)

[Get difference between 2 dates in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3224834/get-difference-between-2-dates-in-javascript/15289883#15289883)