# How to calculate date difference in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, datetime

I want to calculate date difference in days, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds, nanoseconds. How can I do it?

Comment: THe solutions below will break if the two dates involved are in different time-zones. See the question at for a more accurate solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3224834/get-difference-between-2-dates-in-javascript?

Answer (score 328):

Assuming you have two [`Date` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)s, you can just subtract them to get the difference in milliseconds:

```
var difference = date2 - date1;
```

From there, you can use simple arithmetic to derive the other values.

Comment: This is so the right answer. Eg: to get difference in days do `Math.floor((date2 - date1) / (1000*60*60*24))` -- for difference in any other unit, adjust the denominator (the base value is in ms).

Comment: There is no "simple" arithmetic for converting milliseconds to years. You must be aware of bissextile year, of timezone, and some days have 23 or 25 hours. Some years have 365,25 days, so there is no simple arithmetic here (still looking for an accurate solution).

Comment: @Alexandre: The question never asked for years. Indeed, calculating year differences is nontrivial. For days, however, it is correct, supposing the dates are in the same timezone (a not-unreasonable assumption). As far as I know, a day is defined as 24 hours, and any 'variation' in that due to Daylight Savings Time is actually a switch of timezones. If you don't distinguish between timezones already, trying to figure out a time difference is going to put you in a world of hurt, not least because the DST switchover 'repeats' time. Stay in one timezone, though, and it all works.

Comment: @trisweb—even something as simple as getting a difference in days is more complex than your comment. How many days between 10pm Tuesday and 9am Wednesday? Your algorithm says 0. Others might think 1.

Comment: @RobG relativists might even think more than 1 or less than 0. It all depends on the observer.

Comment: The mozilla link is broken

Comment: @icktoofay Depends on the accuracy needed. [Leap seconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_second) do make it more complicated, but you may well be able to get away with such minor inaccuracies...

Comment: If using TypeScript, you might need to use `.getTime()` on each date to not get an error.

Comment: I got "The left-hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type 'any', 'number', 'bigint' or an enum type." I am trying `if ( ( now - prev) > (2*60*1000) ) {`, where both now and prev are Date. I'm using typescript

Answer (score 124):

```
var DateDiff = {
 
    inDays: function(d1, d2) {
        var t2 = d2.getTime();
        var t1 = d1.getTime();
 
        return Math.floor((t2-t1)/(24*3600*1000));
    },
 
    inWeeks: function(d1, d2) {
        var t2 = d2.getTime();
        var t1 = d1.getTime();
 
        return parseInt((t2-t1)/(24*3600*1000*7));
    },
 
    inMonths: function(d1, d2) {
        var d1Y = d1.getFullYear();
        var d2Y = d2.getFullYear();
        var d1M = d1.getMonth();
        var d2M = d2.getMonth();
 
        return (d2M+12*d2Y)-(d1M+12*d1Y);
    },
 
    inYears: function(d1, d2) {
        return d2.getFullYear()-d1.getFullYear();
    }
}
 
var dString = "May, 20, 1984";
 
var d1 = new Date(dString);
var d2 = new Date();
 
document.write("<br />Number of <b>days</b> since "+dString+": "+DateDiff.inDays(d1, d2));
document.write("<br />Number of <b>weeks</b> since "+dString+": "+DateDiff.inWeeks(d1, d2));
document.write("<br />Number of <b>months</b> since "+dString+": "+DateDiff.inMonths(d1, d2));
document.write("<br />Number of <b>years</b> since "+dString+": "+DateDiff.inYears(d1, d2));
```

Code sample taken from [here](http://ditio.net/2010/05/02/javascript-date-difference-calculation/).

Comment: This only returns the date difference in the given format if used as a single counter. For example if you want 3 months 4 days and 5 hours it will NOT produce those results. More in the line of 3 months 96 days and a lot of hours.

Comment: nice and simple

Comment: This doesn't account for daylight savings.

Answer (score 46):

Another solution is convert difference to a new Date object and get that date's year(diff from 1970), month, day etc.

```
var date1 = new Date(2010, 6, 17);
var date2 = new Date(2013, 12, 18);
var diff = new Date(date2.getTime() - date1.getTime());
// diff is: Thu Jul 05 1973 04:00:00 GMT+0300 (EEST)

console.log(diff.getUTCFullYear() - 1970); // Gives difference as year
// 3

console.log(diff.getUTCMonth()); // Gives month count of difference
// 6

console.log(diff.getUTCDate() - 1); // Gives day count of difference
// 4
```

So difference is like "3 years and 6 months and 4 days". If you want to take difference in a human readable style, that can help you.

Comment: It is not the meaning!
We want the WHOLE difference!
In this examp, the differene in days is 1281, not 4!

Comment: @chaim.dev "If you want to take difference in a human readable style, that can help you."

Comment: This is not reliable. It fails to take into account varying month lengths, or leap years and other anomalies.

Comment: Thanks Murat, This solution has solved my issue. What I really want that It must be work in same way like php does.

Comment: This solution only work for timelapse of one year, it fails for more than that because it will never return more than 12 months.

Comment: @RenatoAloi Then it will be 1 year and 1 month....

Answer (score 38):

Expressions like "difference in days" are never as simple as they seem. If you have the following dates:

```
d1: 2011-10-15 23:59:00
d1: 2011-10-16 00:01:00
```

the difference in time is 2 minutes, should the "difference in days" be 1 or 0? Similar issues arise for any expression of the difference in months, years or whatever since years, months and days are of different lengths and different times (e.g. the day that daylight saving starts is 1 hour shorter than usual and two hours shorter than the day that it ends).

Here is a function for a difference in days that ignores the time, i.e. for the above dates it returns 1.

```
/*
   Get the number of days between two dates - not inclusive.

   "between" does not include the start date, so days
   between Thursday and Friday is one, Thursday to Saturday
   is two, and so on. Between Friday and the following Friday is 7.

   e.g. getDaysBetweenDates( 22-Jul-2011, 29-jul-2011) => 7.

   If want inclusive dates (e.g. leave from 1/1/2011 to 30/1/2011),
   use date prior to start date (i.e. 31/12/2010 to 30/1/2011).

   Only calculates whole days.

   Assumes d0 <= d1
*/
function getDaysBetweenDates(d0, d1) {

  var msPerDay = 8.64e7;

  // Copy dates so don't mess them up
  var x0 = new Date(d0);
  var x1 = new Date(d1);

  // Set to noon - avoid DST errors
  x0.setHours(12,0,0);
  x1.setHours(12,0,0);

  // Round to remove daylight saving errors
  return Math.round( (x1 - x0) / msPerDay );
}
```

This can be more concise:

```js
/*  Return number of days between d0 and d1.
**  Returns positive if d0 < d1, otherwise negative.
**
**  e.g. between 2000-02-28 and 2001-02-28 there are 366 days
**       between 2015-12-28 and 2015-12-29 there is 1 day
**       between 2015-12-28 23:59:59 and 2015-12-29 00:00:01 there is 1 day
**       between 2015-12-28 00:00:01 and 2015-12-28 23:59:59 there are 0 days
**        
**  @param {Date} d0  - start date
**  @param {Date} d1  - end date
**  @returns {number} - whole number of days between d0 and d1
**
*/
function daysDifference(d0, d1) {
  var diff = new Date(+d1).setHours(12) - new Date(+d0).setHours(12);
  return Math.round(diff/8.64e7);
}

// Simple formatter
function formatDate(date){
  return [date.getFullYear(),('0'+(date.getMonth()+1)).slice(-2),('0'+date.getDate()).slice(-2)].join('-');
}

// Examples
[[new Date(2000,1,28), new Date(2001,1,28)],  // Leap year
 [new Date(2001,1,28), new Date(2002,1,28)],  // Not leap year
 [new Date(2017,0,1),  new Date(2017,1,1)] 
].forEach(function(dates) {
  document.write('From ' + formatDate(dates[0]) + ' to ' + formatDate(dates[1]) +
                 ' is ' + daysDifference(dates[0],dates[1]) + ' days<br>');
});
```

Comment: @rudeovskizebear—tested in IE, Firefox and Safari, works fine. It uses basic ECMAScript that I'd expect to work in any browser, what doesn't work for you?

Comment: I put it on a test page, and it worked fine in chrome, but i kept getting null back in IE9 and the latest FF

Comment: @RafiB.—I don't know how you think one is more accurate than the other, they do essentially the same thing i.e. calculate the difference in whole days using a UTC time value. The ambiguity in the question was not clarified. If it was, it may lead to a different solution.

Comment: @RobG Please edit the examples in the comments of more concise solution. The month should be '12' not '22'

Comment: incorrect result: `From 28.02.2000, 0:00:00 to 28.02.2001, 0:00:00 is 366 days.` 366 days!

Comment: @IgorKudryashov—not sure of your point. If you add 366 days to 2000-02-28 you'll get 2001-02-28 (though calendar arithmetic is not always symmetric).

Comment: @RobG I just run this code by press button "Run code snippet". I think that this effect can be due to the transition between winter and summer time. In this case, another number of hours is obtained in the day and the formula gives a failure

Comment: @IgorKudryashov—sorry, I'm just not getting it. 2000 is a leap year, so 28 Feb 2000 to 28 Feb 2001 is 366 days. In a non-leap year, it's 365 days. I've added some more examples.

Comment: @RobG Oh yeah! Leap year! Then this code is correct. Sorry!

Answer (score 18):

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<script>
function getDateDiff(time1, time2) {
  var str1= time1.split('/');
  var str2= time2.split('/');

  //                yyyy   , mm       , dd
  var t1 = new Date(str1[2], str1[0]-1, str1[1]);
  var t2 = new Date(str2[2], str2[0]-1, str2[1]);

  var diffMS = t1 - t2;    
  console.log(diffMS + ' ms');

  var diffS = diffMS / 1000;    
  console.log(diffS + ' ');

  var diffM = diffS / 60;
  console.log(diffM + ' minutes');

  var diffH = diffM / 60;
  console.log(diffH + ' hours');

  var diffD = diffH / 24;
  console.log(diffD + ' days');
  alert(diffD);
}

//alert(getDateDiff('10/18/2013','10/14/2013'));
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <input type="button" 
       onclick="getDateDiff('10/18/2013','10/14/2013')" 
       value="clickHere()" />

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Doesn't help me. Can't extend this to months or years in the same approach.

Answer (score 14):

use [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) for all your JavaScript related date-time calculation

Answer to your question is:

```
var a = moment([2007, 0, 29]);   
var b = moment([2007, 0, 28]);    
a.diff(b) // 86400000
```

Complete details can be found [here](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/)

Comment: And embrace the extra 400+ Kb for a mere date difference.

Comment: @RomeoMihalcea Current minified moment.js 2.22.2 with one locale is 53 KB, 17 KB gzipped. I understand your concern though. It's a huge library to use for one simple function, but it takes care of so many date/time related quirks that it's often worth it.

Answer (score 12):

adding to @paresh mayani 's answer, to work like Facebook - showing how much time has passed in sec/min/hours/weeks/months/years

```
var DateDiff = {

  inSeconds: function(d1, d2) {
        var t2 = d2.getTime();
        var t1 = d1.getTime();

        return parseInt((t2-t1)/1000);
    },


  inMinutes: function(d1, d2) {
        var t2 = d2.getTime();
        var t1 = d1.getTime();

        return parseInt((t2-t1)/60000);
    },

  inHours: function(d1, d2) {
        var t2 = d2.getTime();
        var t1 = d1.getTime();

        return parseInt((t2-t1)/3600000);
    },

    inDays: function(d1, d2) {
        var t2 = d2.getTime();
        var t1 = d1.getTime();

        return parseInt((t2-t1)/(24*3600*1000));
    },

    inWeeks: function(d1, d2) {
        var t2 = d2.getTime();
        var t1 = d1.getTime();

        return parseInt((t2-t1)/(24*3600*1000*7));
    },

    inMonths: function(d1, d2) {
        var d1Y = d1.getFullYear();
        var d2Y = d2.getFullYear();
        var d1M = d1.getMonth();
        var d2M = d2.getMonth();

        return (d2M+12*d2Y)-(d1M+12*d1Y);
    },

    inYears: function(d1, d2) {
        return d2.getFullYear()-d1.getFullYear();
    }
}







    var dString = "May, 20, 1984"; //will also get (Y-m-d H:i:s)
    
    var d1 = new Date(dString);
    var d2 = new Date();
    
    var timeLaps = DateDiff.inSeconds(d1, d2);
    var dateOutput = "";
    
    
    if (timeLaps<60)
    {
      dateOutput = timeLaps+" seconds";
    }
    else  
    {
      timeLaps = DateDiff.inMinutes(d1, d2);
      if (timeLaps<60)
      {
        dateOutput = timeLaps+" minutes";
      }
      else
      {
        timeLaps = DateDiff.inHours(d1, d2);
        if (timeLaps<24)
        {
          dateOutput = timeLaps+" hours";
        }
        else
        {
            timeLaps = DateDiff.inDays(d1, d2);
            if (timeLaps<7)
            {
              dateOutput = timeLaps+" days";
            }
            else
            {
                timeLaps = DateDiff.inWeeks(d1, d2);
                if (timeLaps<4)
                {
                  dateOutput = timeLaps+" weeks";
                }
                else
                {
                    timeLaps = DateDiff.inMonths(d1, d2);
                    if (timeLaps<12)
                    {
                      dateOutput = timeLaps+" months";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                      timeLaps = DateDiff.inYears(d1, d2);
                      dateOutput = timeLaps+" years";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
      }
    }
    
    alert (dateOutput);
```

Comment: "May, 20, 1984"; will work on a mobile browser, while "Y-m-d H:i:s" will NOT work on a mobile browser

Comment: And, You can even improve date formatting by using [Intl.RelativeTimeFormat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/RelativeTimeFormat/RelativeTimeFormat)

Answer (score 10):

```
function DateDiff(date1, date2) {
    date1.setHours(0);
    date1.setMinutes(0, 0, 0);
    date2.setHours(0);
    date2.setMinutes(0, 0, 0);
    var datediff = Math.abs(date1.getTime() - date2.getTime()); // difference 
    return parseInt(datediff / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000), 10); //Convert values days and return value      
}
```

Comment: Most solutions that I found either don't work or too long winded. Your solution is the simplest so far and works exactly as intended! Cheers :)

Comment: what if I want to know difference with more precise than one hour? in the post question there is hours and seconds, what for all this zerosettings?

Answer (score 10):

With [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/) it's simple:

```
moment("2016-04-08").fromNow();
```

Comment: moment.js is awesome! :)

Comment: Nice answer, but probably overkill for this specific situation.

Answer (score 7):

```
var d1=new Date(2011,0,1); // jan,1 2011
var d2=new Date(); // now

var diff=d2-d1,sign=diff<0?-1:1,milliseconds,seconds,minutes,hours,days;
diff/=sign; // or diff=Math.abs(diff);
diff=(diff-(milliseconds=diff%1000))/1000;
diff=(diff-(seconds=diff%60))/60;
diff=(diff-(minutes=diff%60))/60;
days=(diff-(hours=diff%24))/24;

console.info(sign===1?"Elapsed: ":"Remains: ",
             days+" days, ",
             hours+" hours, ",
             minutes+" minutes, ",
             seconds+" seconds, ",
             milliseconds+" milliseconds.");
```

Answer (score 6):

I think this should do it.

```
let today = new Date();
let form_date=new Date('2019-10-23')
let difference=form_date>today ? form_date-today : today-form_date
let diff_days=Math.floor(difference/(1000*3600*24))
```

Comment: I had problems with Safari with this solution. My hint is to use `new Date('2019/10/23')` not the version shown above!

Answer (score 6):

based on javascript runtime prototype implementation you can use simple arithmetic to subtract dates as in bellow

```
var sep = new Date(2020, 07, 31, 23, 59, 59);
var today = new Date();
var diffD = Math.floor((sep - today) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
console.log('Day Diff: '+diffD);
```

the difference return answer as milliseconds, then you have to convert it by division:

- by 1000 to convert to second
- by 1000×60 convert to minute
- by 1000×60×60 convert to hour
- by 1000×60×60×24 convert to day

Answer (score 5):

```
function DateDiff(b, e)
{
    let
        endYear = e.getFullYear(),
        endMonth = e.getMonth(),
        years = endYear - b.getFullYear(),
        months = endMonth - b.getMonth(),
        days = e.getDate() - b.getDate();
    if (months < 0)
    {
        years--;
        months += 12;
    }
    if (days < 0)
    {
        months--;
        days += new Date(endYear, endMonth, 0).getDate();
    }
    return [years, months, days];
}

[years, months, days] = DateDiff(
    new Date("October 21, 1980"),
    new Date("July 11, 2017")); // 36 8 20
```

Comment: The scenario below will result in unexpected values
`[years, months, days] = DateDiff(
    new Date("October 21, 2019"),
    new Date("October 18, 2020")); // 1 -1 27
                                                       // 0 11 27 <- should be this`
... To fix this, add the `(months < 0)` condition again below the line of `months--;`

Comment: With @Rivo's fix, this is the simplest and most logical way to do it.

Any other librairies I tried gave me results like "12 months and 4 days"... Sorry what?!?! As far as I know, human readable "12 months" is still 1 year...

So +1 for this solution as it's really purely a comparative difference like a normal human would do. It's not 100% precise at the millisecond, but you rarely reference time differences with precise information. "1 month" is imprecise by nature, it could be 28 days, 30 days or 31 days. This solution takes care of all of that.

Answer (score 5):

This code will return the difference between two dates in days:

```
const previous_date = new Date("2019-12-23");
const current_date = new Date();

const current_year = current_date.getFullYear();
const previous_date_year = 
previous_date.getFullYear();

const difference_in_years = current_year - 
previous_date_year;

let months = current_date.getMonth();
months = months + 1; // for making the indexing 
// of months from 1

for(let i = 0; i < difference_in_years; i++){
months = months + 12;
}

let days = current_date.getDate();

days = days + (months * 30.417);

console.log(`The days between ${current_date} and 
${previous_date} are : ${days} (approximately)`);
```

Comment: Pls, put some additional details and explanations so that others can understand what the code does and use it accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

**Sorry but flat millisecond calculation is not reliable**
Thanks for all the responses, but few of the functions I tried are failing either on 
1. A date near today's date 
2. A date in 1970 or 
3. A date in a leap year.

Approach that best worked for me and covers all scenario e.g. leap year, near date in 1970, feb 29 etc.

```
var someday = new Date("8/1/1985");
var today = new Date();
var years = today.getFullYear() - someday.getFullYear();

// Reset someday to the current year.
someday.setFullYear(today.getFullYear());

// Depending on when that day falls for this year, subtract 1.
if (today < someday)
{
    years--;
}
document.write("Its been " + years + " full years.");
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are using moment.js then it is pretty simple to find date difference.

```
var now  = "04/09/2013 15:00:00";
var then = "04/09/2013 14:20:30";

moment.utc(moment(now,"DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss").diff(moment(then,"DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss"))).format("HH:mm:ss")
```

Answer (score 2):

This is how you can implement difference between dates without a framework.

```
function getDateDiff(dateOne, dateTwo) {
        if(dateOne.charAt(2)=='-' & dateTwo.charAt(2)=='-'){
            dateOne = new Date(formatDate(dateOne));
            dateTwo = new Date(formatDate(dateTwo));
        }
        else{
            dateOne = new Date(dateOne);
            dateTwo = new Date(dateTwo);            
        }
        let timeDiff = Math.abs(dateOne.getTime() - dateTwo.getTime());
        let diffDays = Math.ceil(timeDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24));
        let diffMonths = Math.ceil(diffDays/31);
        let diffYears = Math.ceil(diffMonths/12);

        let message = "Difference in Days: " + diffDays + " " +
                      "Difference in Months: " + diffMonths+ " " + 
                      "Difference in Years: " + diffYears;
        return message;
     }

    function formatDate(date) {
         return date.split('-').reverse().join('-');
    }

    console.log(getDateDiff("23-04-2017", "23-04-2018"));
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
function daysInMonth (month, year) {
    return new Date(year, month, 0).getDate();
}
function getduration(){

let A= document.getElementById("date1_id").value
let B= document.getElementById("date2_id").value

let C=Number(A.substring(3,5))
let D=Number(B.substring(3,5))
let dif=D-C
let arr=[];
let sum=0;
for (let i=0;i<dif+1;i++){
  sum+=Number(daysInMonth(i+C,2019))
}
let sum_alter=0;
for (let i=0;i<dif;i++){
  sum_alter+=Number(daysInMonth(i+C,2019))
}
let no_of_month=(Number(B.substring(3,5)) - Number(A.substring(3,5)))
let days=[];
if ((Number(B.substring(3,5)) - Number(A.substring(3,5)))>0||Number(B.substring(0,2)) - Number(A.substring(0,2))<0){
days=Number(B.substring(0,2)) - Number(A.substring(0,2)) + sum_alter
}

if ((Number(B.substring(3,5)) == Number(A.substring(3,5)))){
console.log(Number(B.substring(0,2)) - Number(A.substring(0,2)) + sum_alter)
}

time_1=[]; time_2=[]; let hour=[];
 time_1=document.getElementById("time1_id").value
 time_2=document.getElementById("time2_id").value
  if (time_1.substring(0,2)=="12"){
     time_1="00:00:00 PM"
  }
if (time_1.substring(9,11)==time_2.substring(9,11)){
hour=Math.abs(Number(time_2.substring(0,2)) - Number(time_1.substring(0,2)))
}
if (time_1.substring(9,11)!=time_2.substring(9,11)){
hour=Math.abs(Number(time_2.substring(0,2)) - Number(time_1.substring(0,2)))+12
}
let min=Math.abs(Number(time_1.substring(3,5))-Number(time_2.substring(3,5)))
document.getElementById("duration_id").value=days +" days "+ hour+"  hour " + min+"  min " 
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="date1_id" placeholder="28/05/2019">
<input type="text" id="date2_id" placeholder="29/06/2019">
<br><br>
<input type="text" id="time1_id" placeholder="08:01:00 AM">
<input type="text" id="time2_id" placeholder="00:00:00 PM">
<br><br>
<button class="text" onClick="getduration()">Submit </button>
<br><br>
<input type="text" id="duration_id" placeholder="days hour min">
```

Comment: This code gives accurate results about the no of days, time and even minutes

Comment: Hope you guys using it

Answer (score 2):

```
var date1 = new Date("06/30/2019");
var date2 = new Date("07/30/2019");
  
// To calculate the time difference of two dates
var Difference_In_Time = date2.getTime() - date1.getTime();
  
// To calculate the no. of days between two dates
var Difference_In_Days = Difference_In_Time / (1000 * 3600 * 24);
  
//To display the final no. of days (result)
document.write("Total number of days between dates  <br>"
               + date1 + "<br> and <br>" 
               + date2 + " is: <br> " 
               + Difference_In_Days);
```

Answer (score 1):

this should work just fine if you just need to show what time left, since JavaScript uses frames for its time you'll have get your End Time - The Time RN after that we can divide it by 1000 since apparently 1000 frames = 1 seconds, after that you can use the basic math of time, but there's still a problem to this code, since the calculation is static, it can't compensate for the different day total in a year (360/365/366), the bunch of IF after the calculation is to make it null if the time is lower than 0, hope this helps even though it's not exactly what you're asking :)

```
var now = new Date();
var end = new Date("End Time");
var total = (end - now) ;
var totalD =  Math.abs(Math.floor(total/1000));

var years = Math.floor(totalD / (365*60*60*24));
var months = Math.floor((totalD - years*365*60*60*24) / (30*60*60*24));
var days = Math.floor((totalD - years*365*60*60*24 - months*30*60*60*24)/ (60*60*24));
var hours = Math.floor((totalD - years*365*60*60*24 - months*30*60*60*24 - days*60*60*24)/ (60*60));
var minutes = Math.floor((totalD - years*365*60*60*24 - months*30*60*60*24 - days*60*60*24 - hours*60*60)/ (60));
var seconds = Math.floor(totalD - years*365*60*60*24 - months*30*60*60*24 - days*60*60*24 - hours*60*60 - minutes*60);

var Y = years < 1 ? "" : years + " Years ";
var M = months < 1 ? "" : months + " Months ";
var D = days < 1 ? "" : days + " Days ";
var H = hours < 1 ? "" : hours + " Hours ";
var I = minutes < 1 ? "" : minutes + " Minutes ";
var S = seconds < 1 ? "" : seconds + " Seconds ";
var A = years == 0 && months == 0 && days == 0 && hours == 0 && minutes == 0 && seconds == 0 ? "Sending" : " Remaining";

document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML = Y + M + D + H + I + S + A;
```

Answer (score 1):

I made a below function to get the difference between **now** and `"2021-02-26T21:50:42.123"`.

The difference return answer as milliseconds, so I convert it by using this formula:

`(1000 * 3600 * 24)`.

```
function getDiff(dateAcquired) {
      let calDiff = Math.floor(
        (new Date() - new Date(dateAcquired)) / (1000 * 3600 * 24)
      );
      return calDiff;
    }
    console.log(getDiff("2021-02-26T21:50:42.123"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, there are a bunch of ways you can do that.
Yes, you can use plain old JS. Just try:

```
let dt1 = new Date()
let dt2 = new Date()
```

Let's emulate passage using Date.prototype.setMinutes and make sure we are in range.

```
dt1.setMinutes(7)
dt2.setMinutes(42)
console.log('Elapsed seconds:',(dt2-dt1)/1000)
```

Alternatively you could use some library like [**js-joda**](https://js-joda.github.io/js-joda/manual/LocalDateTime.html), where you can easily do things like this (directly from docs):

```
var dt1 = LocalDateTime.parse("2016-02-26T23:55:42.123");
var dt2 = dt1
  .plusYears(6)
  .plusMonths(12)
  .plusHours(2)
  .plusMinutes(42)
  .plusSeconds(12);

// obtain the duration between the two dates
dt1.until(dt2, ChronoUnit.YEARS); // 7
dt1.until(dt2, ChronoUnit.MONTHS); // 84
dt1.until(dt2, ChronoUnit.WEEKS); // 356
dt1.until(dt2, ChronoUnit.DAYS); // 2557
dt1.until(dt2, ChronoUnit.HOURS); // 61370
dt1.until(dt2, ChronoUnit.MINUTES); // 3682242
dt1.until(dt2, ChronoUnit.SECONDS); // 220934532
```

There are plenty more libraries ofc, but js-joda has an added bonus of being available also in Java, where it has been extensively tested. All those tests have been migrated to js-joda, it's also immutable.

Answer (score 0):

Can be useful :

```
const date_diff = (date1, date2) => Math.ceil(Math.abs(date1 - date2)/24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)
```

or

```
const date_diff = (date1, date2) => Math.ceil(Math.abs(date1 - date2)/86400000)
```

where 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 is (day * minutes * seconds * milliseconds) = 86400000 milliseconds in one day

Thank you

Comment: Not `/ 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000` but `/ (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)`

Answer (score -2):

```
            // the idea is to get time left for new year.
           // Not considering milliseconds as of now, but that 
           //  can be done
           
            var newYear = '1 Jan 2023';
            const secondsInAMin = 60;
            const secondsInAnHour = 60 * secondsInAMin;
            const secondsInADay = 24 * secondsInAnHour;

            function DateDiffJs() {
                var newYearDate = new Date(newYear);
                var currDate = new Date();

                var remainingSecondsInDateDiff = (newYearDate - currDate) / 1000;
                var days = Math.floor(remainingSecondsInDateDiff / secondsInADay);

                var remainingSecondsAfterDays = remainingSecondsInDateDiff - (days * secondsInADay);
                var hours = Math.floor(remainingSecondsAfterDays / secondsInAnHour);

                var remainingSecondsAfterhours = remainingSecondsAfterDays - (hours * secondsInAnHour);
                var mins = Math.floor(remainingSecondsAfterhours / secondsInAMin);

                var seconds = Math.floor(remainingSecondsAfterhours - (mins * secondsInAMin));


                console.log(`days :: ${days}`)
                console.log(`hours :: ${hours}`)
                console.log(`mins :: ${mins}`)
                console.log(`seconds :: ${seconds}`)

            }

            DateDiffJs();
```