# calculate days between dates

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to calculate the days between 2 dates but just keep getting "NaN. I've looked at other posts but can't quite work it out :-S

```
function checkdate() {

var currentTime = new Date()
var month = currentTime.getMonth() + 1
var day = currentTime.getDate()
var year = currentTime.getFullYear()
var datenow = (day + "/" + month + "/" + year)  


var startdate = document.forms[0].datescopestart.value;
var sDate = new Date(Date.parse("startdate","dd/mm/yy"));

var totaldays = Date.datenow - Date.sDate;  
    alert(totaldays);
    }
```

Comment: This isn't your problem, but don't forget your semicolons.

Comment: `Date.datenow` and `Date.sDate` do not exist.

Comment: Duplication of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7763327/how-to-calculate-date-difference-in-javascript

Comment: This has been asked a few times on stackoverflow - http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=javascript+days+between+two+dates

Answer (score 3):

Here's the function I've had in my library for a while now, works great.

```
function days_between(date1, date2) {

  // The number of milliseconds in one day
  var ONE_DAY = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24

  // Convert both dates to milliseconds
  var date1_ms = date1.getTime()
  var date2_ms = date2.getTime()

  // Calculate the difference in milliseconds
  var difference_ms = Math.abs(date1_ms - date2_ms)

  // Convert back to days and return
  return Math.round(difference_ms/ONE_DAY)

}
```

Comment: But what about leap seconds?  :O

Answer (score 1):

Remove the quotes around `startdate` in the call to `Date.parse`. And the `Date.` in front of your variable names in the calculation.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is as follows:

```
var days = Math.floor(enddate.getTime()-startdate.getTime())/(24*60*60*1000);
```

Where `startdate` and `enddate` are valid Date objects.

Comment: if i'm collecting a date from a form field like this: var startdate = document.forms[0].datescopestart.value; The format returned is dd/mm/yyyy i.e 23/07/2012 How do I turn it into a vaild date oject?