# java script how to get a date range in days

Tags: javascript, jquery, date-range

I have these date variables

```
minVal = new Date(parseInt(dateArr[2]), parseInt(dateArr[0]) - 1, parseInt(dateArr[1]), 00, 00, 00);
maxVal = new Date(parseInt(dateArrTo[2]), parseInt(dateArrTo[0]) - 1, parseInt(dateArrTo[1]), 23, 59, 59);
```

I use them to draw charts.

I need to differentiate between two things:

1. During 30 days charts.
2. After 30 days charts.

Thus, I need to know the different between these dates in **days**

I tried to do this:

```
if ((maxVal.getMonth() - minVal.getMonth()) == 0)
```

It works with some values and doesn't work with some values. For example, if the minimum date is `29 January 2014` and the maximum date is `01 February 2014` it doesn't work.
I know that because I am calculating the months.

**But I don't know how to calculate the days**

I know that `getDate()` function retrieves the days number but I really couldn't know how to use it.

your help is appreciated

Comment: There are tons of questions like this, see one of them http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7763327/how-to-calculate-date-difference-in-javascript

Comment: @Deele these are long functions. I believe there is something easier, right?

Comment: @user3432257 try the solution provided by me. It supports both calendar and business days

Comment: @KailashYadav I am trying to read it thought it is long

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
function workingDaysBetweenDates(startDate, endDate, getWorkingDays) {

    startDate = new Date(startDate);
    endDate = new Date(endDate);

    // Validate input
    if (endDate < startDate)
        return 0;

    // Calculate days between dates
    var millisecondsPerDay = 86400 * 1000; // Day in milliseconds
    startDate.setHours(0,0,0,1);  // Start just after midnight
    endDate.setHours(23,59,59,999);  // End just before midnight
    var diff = endDate - startDate;  // Milliseconds between datetime objects
    var days = Math.ceil(diff / millisecondsPerDay);

    if(getWorkingDays){
        // Subtract two weekend days for every week in between
        var weeks = Math.floor(days / 7);
        days = days - (weeks * 2);

        // Handle special cases
        var startDay = startDate.getDay();
        var endDay = endDate.getDay();

        // Remove weekend not previously removed.
        if (startDay - endDay > 1)
            days = days - 2;

        // Remove start day if span starts on Sunday but ends before Saturday
        if (startDay == 0 && endDay != 6)
            days = days - 1;

        // Remove end day if span ends on Saturday but starts after Sunday
        if (endDay == 6 && startDay != 0)
            days = days - 1;
    }
    return days;
}

workingDaysBetweenDates(start_date, end_date, false);
```

Here is the working Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kailashyadav/72b27/

Date format needs be one of these: 04/24/2014 or 2014-04-24

The third parameter is whether you want to get business or calendar days

Comment: I don't want to set hours. because in my business, I set the hour myself.

Comment: can I stop on this line `var days = Math.ceil(diff / millisecondsPerDay);` ? I mean in this line I will be getting the days number, right?

Comment: You can and `var days` will give you the `number of days`. Make sure you check `var days = Math.ceil(diff / millisecondsPerDay);` as `Math.ceil` will round off the value.