# Jquery CountUP timer from specific date

Tags: jquery, date, timer, web, counter

I need countUP timer from the specific date. (year, month, day, hour, min., sec.,)

For example I need count up timer from date 2012 August 24, and when I refresh the page, timer must still work/count UP.

I found so many counter but every counter is DOWN, not UP.

This timerlook so good
http://flipclockjs.com/

but missing count UP from specific date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, since you've mentioned FlipClock, I guess this should work:

Calculate difference between current date and your desired date:

```
var date1 = new Date("8/24/2012");
var date2 = new Date();
var timeDiff = Math.abs(date2.getTime() - date1.getTime());
var diffSeconds = Math.ceil(timeDiff / 1000);
```

Create FlipClock (it counts up by default, to change that set countdown: true):

```
var clock = $('.your-clock').FlipClock({
    // ... your options here
});
```

Use `setTime()` method to set time:

```
clock.setTime(diffSeconds);
```

Now just start the clock:

```
clock.start();
```

I haven't checked this, but should work according to documentation.

**Edit:**

Since FlipClock doesn't support nothing beyond 99 days, here is another approach with [Countdown.js](http://countdownjs.org/):

```
setInterval(function() {
    var timespan = countdown(new Date("08/24/2012"), new Date());
    var div = document.getElementById('time');
    div.innerHTML = "Time difference with 08/24/2012 is " + timespan.years + " years, " + timespan.months + " months, " + timespan.days + " days, " + timespan.hours + " hours, " + timespan.minutes + " minutes, " + timespan.seconds + " seconds."
}, 1000);
```

See [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/brkp1sa2/).

Comment: Great!

But Flipclock have only DailyCounter, not have month and year. This timer counts only to 99 days.

I need change this code

var clock = $('.clock').FlipClock({
    clockFace: 'DailyCounter',
});


But flipclock don't offer option what I need

Comment: Well, you need to either create your own face (http://flipclockjs.com/api), or choose another counter that supports years and do the same steps I described (calculating date difference).

Comment: ok, I change my requirements.

What if I want show only the timeDiff in static number, not live view countUP.

I come to the page, and I see how long is it from the date what I set, not count UP, only static number. And then, when I reload the page, script again calculate the difference and show it on the page.

Comment: You can do this either using countdown.js: `var timespan = countdown(new Date("08/12/2012"), new Date());`, or using plain javascript: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20669357/2571926

Comment: AWESOME! AWESOME! AWESOME! Thank you so so mutch! thats what I need! :)

Comment: You're welcome. Note: you need only `setInterval` part. The script above it is actually this one: https://bitbucket.org/mckamey/countdown.js/raw/tip/countdown.min.js, simply include it as a script link. I couldn't add it to jsfiddle otherwise unfortunately.