# jQuery invalid date error

Tags: javascript, date

Why is the first date invalid? I don't understand.

https://jsfiddle.net/r4dgjdn6/1/

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  alert(new Date('19.12.2016 14:00'));
  alert(new Date('12.12.2016 14:00'));

});
```

I want to calculate date difference but i keep getting the Invalid Date error.

Comment: Is there a 19th month?

Comment: oh i see now...i am in Germany and we write first the day and then the month!

Comment: @lewis4u Unfortunately you have to accept with Javascript that the (illogical and obviously wrong ;-) American date format is mandatory!

Comment: can i somehow parse it to my local format

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the library http://momentjs.com/ and use it like this:

```
var a = moment('19.12.2016 14:00', 'DD.MM.YYYY mm:ss');
var b = moment('12.12.2016 14:00', 'DD.MM.YYYY mm:ss');

//to calculate the diff
a.diff(b);
```

Comment: did you try it in fiddle??

Comment: the problem is that i already have the input format like 'DD.MM.YYYY mm:ss' and i need to parse that as a date. But how?

Comment: sorry, i'm new here so i updated directly my response

Comment: cool, this library is realy interesting, so look at its [documentation](http://momentjs.com/docs/)

Answer (score 2):

because the 'date' constructor can get specific "date format" as parameters

for example :

```
alert(new Date('Mon Dec 19 2016 14:00:00'));
```

take a look at this :

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_dates.asp

EDIT:

if it is always in this format you can use this "quick" code to parse your string into the right format:

```
var inputString = '19.12.2016 14:00';
var tmpArray = inputString.split('.');
var result = tmpArray[1] + "-" + tmpArray[0] + "-" + tmpArray[2].split(' ')[0] + " " + tmpArray[2].split(' ')[1];
alert(new Date(result));
```

Comment: and for thr difference between dates take a look at that : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7763327/how-to-calculate-date-difference-in-javascript

Comment: ok and how can i parse the date from my input field if it's value is just like in my question `19.12.2016 14:00`

Comment: moment.js is my answer

Comment: gave you quick no thinking code for your problem, of course its not generic its only for your case only :)

Comment: if you have libary of course its better, but next time mentiond it in your question that you dont mind using libaries ;)

Comment: why it doesn't work again even with the library?? https://jsfiddle.net/pxxLzdvf/2/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130964/discussion-between-lewis4u-and-oriel-f).

Comment: Please don't reference w3schools, the site is full of bad advice and errors. Please use ECMA-262 or MDN.