# get hours + minutes from a long timestamp, javascript

Tags: javascript, time, difference

first attempt:

```
let time1 = new Date("September 24 2018 22:20");
let time2 = new Date("September 25 2018 02:00");

let diff = time2 - time1;
console.log(diff); // 13200000
let result = Math.abs(time1 - time2);
console.log(result); //13200

let hours = Math.floor(result / 3600) % 24;
console.log("Difference (Hours): " + hours); //3
let minutes = Math.floor(result / 60) % 60;
console.log("Difference (Minutes): " + minutes);//40
```

second attempt:

```
let options = { timeZone: 'UTC', timeZoneName: 'short'};
let time1 = new Date("September 24 2018 22:20");
let time2 = new Date("September 25 2018 02:00");

let diff = time2 - time1;
console.log(diff); //13200000
let result = new Date(diff);
console.log(result.toLocaleTimeString("de-DE", options)); //03:40:00 UTC
```

So, these two ex. work just fine, but only if the maximum difference between the dates is 23:59.
But I want hours and minutes displayed over more than 23:59 like for ex, date1 = two weeks ago on a friday 22:43, date2 = today / 2days ahead etc, so I get a result like 127:44, or 54:52 or 48:33.

I know I am doing something wrong, but what ?

Comment: `diff` will be in **milliseconds** not **seconds**

Comment: you can have a look on this questions https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42454564/getting-the-difference-between-2-dates-in-javascript-in-hours-minutes-seconds

Comment: @DILEEPTHOMAS, Thomas ma men, have a cookie. This is spot on, I just had to add the hours and minutes after the specified date, and it works. Thanks a lot !

Comment: @nooby happy coding :)