# Get age in days from firebase date

Tags: javascript, date, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have an app that posts to a firebase database.  I am storing data such as the date created, id, description, etc.  How can I figure the age of the posts in days using javascript?

Date Created:

```
$scope.products = [];
    firebase.database().ref('products').orderByChild('rank').startAt(0).endAt(10000).limitToLast(10).once('value', function(products) {

        products.forEach(function(product) {
          var product = {
            date: product.val().dateCreated,
            id: product.key,
            name: product.val().name

          };
```

returns `Sun May 21 2017 00:12:13 GMT-0500 (CDT)`

and current date:

```
$scope.date = Date();
```

returns `Wed May 31 2017 11:12:06 GMT-0500 (CDT)`

Given the above, I want to output `10` from the difference in the dates .  How should I proceed?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can use Date.prototype.getTime() on both and subtract afterwards.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [*How to calculate date difference in javascript*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7763327/how-to-calculate-date-difference-in-javascript).

Comment: @xDreamCoding - got it using getTime().  Thx..