# Why subsract Date Objects doesn't works

Tags: javascript

I have that function:

```
function CompareDate() {
    var timeNow = '03.04.2019';
    var timeNowSplit = timeNow.split('.');
    var timeTarget = '04.04.2019';
    var timeTargetSplit = timeTarget.split('.');

    var timeNowObj = new Date(timeNowSplit[2], timeNowSplit[1], timeNowSplit[0]).toUTCString();
    var timeTargetObj = new Date(timeTargetSplit[2], timeTargetSplit[1], timeTargetSplit[0]).toUTCString();

    difference = timeTargetObj - timeNowObj;
    console.log(difference)
}
```

If i'm launching this inside a node.js console i'm getting just:

> "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe"
>   C:\Users\s.manns.WebStorm2018.3\config\scratches\scratch.js
>       NaN

That solution i found on [How to calculate date difference in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7763327/how-to-calculate-date-difference-in-javascript)

But why this code just returns a "NaN"?

Comment: Remove the `.toUTCString()` bit from both and just subtract the date objects

Comment: ...and Month is `monthIndex` - Integer value representing the month, beginning with `0` for January to `11` for December. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is because you are attempting to calculate the difference of two strings. Remove the `toUTCString()` from both and it will result in a valid response. For completeness, please note the response you receive will be in milliseconds!

```js
var timeNow = '03.04.2019';
    var timeNowSplit = timeNow.split('.');
    var timeTarget = '04.04.2019';
    var timeTargetSplit = timeTarget.split('.');

    var timeNowObj = new Date(timeNowSplit[2], timeNowSplit[1]-1, timeNowSplit[0]);
    var timeTargetObj = new Date(timeTargetSplit[2], timeTargetSplit[1]-1, timeTargetSplit[0]);

    difference = timeTargetObj - timeNowObj;
    console.log(difference);
```

Answer (score 0):

The method you are using `Data.prototype.toUTCString()` which changes the date object to UTC equivalent string. Try removing the method and then subtract.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you -

```
function CompareDate() {
    var timeNow = '03.04.2019';
    var timeNowSplit = timeNow.split('.');
    var timeTarget = '04.04.2019';
    var timeTargetSplit = timeTarget.split('.');

    var timeNowObj = new Date(timeNowSplit[2], timeNowSplit[1], timeNowSplit[0]);
    var timeTargetObj = new Date(timeTargetSplit[2], timeTargetSplit[1], timeTargetSplit[0]);

    difference = timeTargetObj - timeNowObj;
    console.log(difference)
}
CompareDate();
```