# DateDiff from four dates

Tags: javascript, datediff

I am trying to calculate the service time for some one from two different periods of time.
I have been using a DateDiff script which is fine for displaying between two dates (Below):

```
<center>
<font face=glegoo size=4 color=#909090>
<script type="text/javascript">
var DateDiff = {

    inDays: function(d1, d2) {
        var t2 = d2.getTime();
        var t1 = d1.getTime();

        return parseInt((t2-t1)/(24*3600*1000));
    },

    inWeeks: function(d1, d2) {
        var t2 = d2.getTime();
        var t1 = d1.getTime();

        return parseInt((t2-t1)/(24*3600*1000*7));
    },

    inMonths: function(d1, d2) {
        var d1Y = d1.getFullYear();
        var d2Y = d2.getFullYear();
        var d1M = d1.getMonth();
        var d2M = d2.getMonth();

        return (d2M+12*d2Y)-(d1M+12*d1Y);
    },

    inYears: function(d1, d2) {
        return d2.getFullYear()-d1.getFullYear();
    }
}

var dString = "May, 23, 2016";

var d1 = new Date(dString);
var d2 = new Date();

document.write("Service:&nbsp;&nbsp;-&nbsp; "+DateDiff.inYears(d1, d2));
document.write("&nbsp;&nbsp;Years");

</script>
</font>
</center>
```

But I wan to add the service time from a previous period and then combine this together, displaying total years and months.
I have tried "Doubling" the script in my own stuffed up way, but now starting to bang my head against the desk. I can't seem to figure out how to increase a year when months calculate more than 12 months.
This is what I got to:

```
<center>
<font face=glegoo size=4 color=#909090>
<script type="text/javascript">
var DateDiff = {

    inDays: function(d1, d2, d3, d4) {
        var t2 = d2.getTime();
        var t1 = d1.getTime();
        var t4 = d4.getTime();
        var t3 = d3.getTime();

        return parseInt((t2-t1)/(24*3600*1000)+(t4-t3)/(24*3600*1000));
    },

    inWeeks: function(d1, d2, d3, d4) {
        var t2 = d2.getTime();
        var t1 = d1.getTime();
        var t4 = d4.getTime();
        var t3 = d3.getTime();

        return parseInt((t2-t1)/(24*3600*1000*7)+(t4-t3)/(24*3600*1000*7));
    },

    inMonths: function(d1, d2, d3, d4) {
        var d1Y = d1.getFullYear();
        var d2Y = d2.getFullYear();
        var d1M = d1.getMonth();
        var d2M = d2.getMonth();
        var d3Y = d3.getFullYear();
        var d4Y = d4.getFullYear();
        var d3M = d3.getMonth();
        var d4M = d4.getMonth();

        return (((d2M+12*d2Y)-(d1M+12*d1Y))+((d4M+12*d4Y)-(d3M+12*d3Y)));
    },

    inYears: function(d1, d2, d3, d4) {
        var d1Y = d1.getFullYear();
        var d2Y = d2.getFullYear();
        var d3Y = d3.getFullYear();
        var d4Y = d4.getFullYear();

        return ((d2Y-d1Y)+(d4Y-d3Y));
    }
}


var aString = "April, 24, 2010";
var bString = "May, 24, 2011";
var dString = "May, 23, 2016";


var d1 = new Date(aString);
var d2 = new Date(bString);
var d3 = new Date(dString);
var d4 = new Date();


document.write("Service:&nbsp;&nbsp;-&nbsp; "+DateDiff.inYears(d1, d2, d3, d4)  +"&nbsp; Years &nbsp;&nbsp;" +DateDiff.inMonths(d1, d2, d3, d4));
document.write("&nbsp;&nbsp;Months");

</script>
</font>
</center>
```

Any Help is very much gratefully received.

Comment: `<font>` and `<center>` tags? `document.write`? Logic is also wrong. Start all over.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to calculate date difference in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7763327/how-to-calculate-date-difference-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

It could be much simpler using this:

`var difference = date2 - date1;`

Have a look here: [How to calculate date difference in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7763327/how-to-calculate-date-difference-in-javascript)
The first comment will tell you how to get this in days, or other unit. Just make sure that `date2` is bigger (after) `date1`!

Comment: Please don’t answer with a link to another question’s answer. Please flag the question as a duplicate of that other question.

Comment: Thank you. I will have a play with that as well.

But if I have two different caluations for two different periods, example below, how can these be added together?

1st Jan 2018 - 1st Nov 2018 (10 months)
1st May 2015 - Present day (4years, 8months)

This should display as 5years, 6months. but actually displays as 4years, 18months

Comment: `var diff = (date2 - date1) + (date4 - date3)` and then you convert this (ms) into what you anna get.