# Take date input from user and calculate difference between dates using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Taking the user input for date using

```
<input type="date" id="date1" onchange='leavenumber();'/>
<input type="date" id="date2" onchange='leavenumber();'/>
```

I want to calculate the difference between two dates using javascript.

I have tried using below function but it doesnot work:

```
var leavenumber = function(){
        const date1 = document.getElementById("date1").value;
        const date2 = document.getElementById("date2").value;
        const diffTime = Math.abs(date2 - date1);
        const diffDays = Math.ceil(diffTime / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
        console.log(diffDays);
       }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to calculate date difference in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7763327/how-to-calculate-date-difference-in-javascript)

Comment: No, it returns NaN instead.

Comment: @Error No, it doesn’t. The top answer starts with _“Assuming you have two `Date` objects”_. Neither `date1` nor `date2` are `Date` objects. With proper `Date` objects from correctly filled out `<input>`s, you won’t get `NaN`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `document.getElementById("date").value`  you should use `document.getElementById("date").valueAsDate` which gives you a `Date` object instead of a raw string which can be used for further calculations.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest using the library [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/). This way you can measure the difference very easily - in days, hours, etc. I give you example with difference measured in days.

```
var leavenumber = function(){
        var date1 = moment(document.getElementById("date1").value);
        var date2 = moment(document.getElementById("date2").value);
        if (date1.isValid() && date2.isValid()) {
            console.log(date1.diff(date2, 'days'))
        }
       }
```

[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zafbco2q/2/)