# Different of Date gives a null result in javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, date

My goal is to make a time countdown component. I must show a difference of date from current date to user-entered date, in Year Month Day Hour Min Sec format.

I tried to minus the two dates but ended up with 00:00:00:00. Adding them gave me a result but minus gives me this 00.

Other answers do not satisfy requirements or explain why I get a difference of 0 when subtracting dates.

**my code:**

```
import "./App.css";
import Countdown from "react-countdown";

function App() {
  console.log(Date.now());

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello</h1>
      <form>
        <input type="date" />
        <button>submit</button>
      </form>
      <Countdown date={new Date(2021, 6, 10) + Date.now()} />,
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add days to JavaScript Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/563406/add-days-to-javascript-date)

Comment: @tevemadar Nope.

Comment: Sorry, wrong paste. This is the one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7763327/how-to-calculate-date-difference-in-javascript

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to calculate date difference in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7763327/how-to-calculate-date-difference-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

You can either do it manually as

```
function addDays(date, days) {
  var result = new Date(date);
  result.setDate(result.getDate() + days);
  return result;
}
```

or use moment js ( https://momentjs.com/ ) for operations

Comment: I can't do this, as Countdown is a npm package

Comment: Yes you can, you must process the date before passing it to Countdown. In order to do that you can do it manually or use momentjs as the answer explains.

Answer (score 0):

using moment.js, you can do it in this way:

```
const diffDates = (start, end) => {
  let a = moment(start);
  let b = moment(end);
  return a.diff(b, "days");
};
```