# Difference between two dates. react-native (js)

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am trying to get the time that has happened between two dates.
Example:

oldDate = "4/16/2020, 12:00:00"

today = "5/17/2021, 1:00:50"

Result that a need:

years = 1

months = 1

days = 1

hours = 1

minutes = 0

seconds = 50

I also would like to refresh it every second, so that, the user can see it running.
Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to calculate date difference in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7763327/how-to-calculate-date-difference-in-javascript)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Date.parse()` to get a `Date` object from a string, subtract two dates using the `-` operator, and get the number of years, months, days, etc. using the corresponding methods. Then use `setInterval` to run it every second, and `Date.now()` to get the current time.

```js
const oldDate = Date.parse("4/10/2020, 12:00:00");

// weird but seems to work with all dates 
const getYear = (date) => date.getFullYear() - 1970;
const timeBetweenDates = (date1, date2) => {
  const date = new Date(date1 - date2);
  return {
    years: getYear(date),
    months: date.getMonth(),
    days: date.getDay(),
    hours: date.getHours(),
    minutes: date.getMinutes(),
    seconds: date.getSeconds(),
  }
}
const pre = document.getElementById("display");
setInterval(() => {
  pre.textContent = JSON.stringify(
    timeBetweenDates(Date.now(), oldDate),
    0, 
    2
  );
}, 1000);
```

```html
<pre id="display">Wait a second...</pre>
```

Comment: nice answer,  but use `getFullYear()`, `getYear()` is only usable because of compatibility issues

Comment: Oh, okay! I'll fix that now.

Comment: you dont need anymore the `70` substraction and also the slice is buggy. what happens when you have over 100 years difference?

Comment: Ooh fair enough. I will think a little harder and edit the solution.

Comment: I just realize that days return the following:

Comment: monday = 1, tuesday=2