# calculate duration in Typescript (hours, minutes, secondes)

Tags: angular, typescript

I want calculate duration Between 2 date in TypseScript (Angular): `2021-11-19 21:59:59`    and `2021-11-19 22:00:18`

```
let startdDate: Date = new Date(start);
  let endDate: Date = new Date(end);
  if(end!=null) {
    let duration = new Date(endDate.getTime() - startdDate.getTime());
    return duration.getHours() + ":" +  duration.getMinutes() + ":" + duration.getSeconds();
  } else {
    return "";
  }
```

but my result is wrong: `1:0:19`.

I want `00:00:19`

**EDIT**

I try this but result is wrong again: `01:00:19`

```
const datepipe: DatePipe = new DatePipe('en-US')
let formattedDate = datepipe.transform(duration, 'HH:mm:ss')
```

Comment: Check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7763327/how-to-calculate-date-difference-in-javascript and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3224834/get-difference-between-2-dates-in-javascript

Comment: @MaksatRahmanov, is it a javascript (not typescrit). And in my case I have one hour of error.

Comment: Have you tried `return duration.getUTCHours() + ":" +  duration.getUTCMinutes() + ":" + duration.getUTCSeconds()` ?

Comment: @GOTO0, your solution work but with this result: `0:0:19`. is it possible format to `00:00:19` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can return the time value of date using `toLocaleTimeString()` function this will return only time according to region. Here you can find [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleTimeString).

So in code just change the return statement to this

```
return duration.toLocaleTimeString([], {
   timeZone: 'UTC',
});
```

Comment: `toLocaleTimeString` return the same error (one hour left)

Comment: @StéphaneGRILLON should be okay after this edit

Comment: great, thank you. it works with your solution

Comment: During testing it I found out that if the diff is smaller than 1 hour instead of `0:07:00` it shows `12:07:00`

Comment: No, is it correct if I test `2021-11-20 04:59:59` and  `2021-11-20 06:01:18` the result is `01:01:19`