# How can I execute a condition using new Date in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native

I have a `curTime` variable that is the current time using `new Date()` and a `pwChangeDate` value called from the backend data.

```
  let curTime = new Date();       // Thu Oct 27 2022 15:02:34 GMT+0900
  const pwDate = new Date(pwChangeDate)    // Thu Oct 20 2022 13:51:57 GMT+0900
```

At this time, when `pwDate` passes 90 days based on `curTime`, I want to display an alert saying "90 days have passed." and when 83 days have passed, "7 days left out of 90 days." I want to display an alert.

but if i use my code it doesn't work how can i fix it?

```
  const pwChangeDate = cookie.get('pwChangeDate');
  const pwDate = new Date(pwChangeDate)

  if (curTime.getDate() >=  pwDate.getDate() - 90) {
    alert('90 days have passed.')
  }

  if (curTime.getDate() >=  pwDate.getDate() - 7) {
    alert('7 days left out of 90 days..')
  }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to calculate date difference in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7763327/how-to-calculate-date-difference-in-javascript)

Comment: `getDate` returns day of month, so `curTime.getDate() >=  pwDate.getDate() - 90` makes no sense

Comment: also [dayjs().subtract(90, 'days')](https://day.js.org/docs/en/manipulate/subtract)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to calcuate the days difference between `pwDate` and `curTime`, you can calculate like this.

```
Math.floor((pwDate.getTime() - curTime.getTime()) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
```

`getTime()` method returns a time value as milliseconds.

`1000 * 60 * 60 * 24` is milliseconds per day.

OR

Using some library. ([date-and-time](https://github.com/knowledgecode/date-and-time#subtractdate1-date2))

Answer (score 2):

you can get the diff between current data and pwDate in days like this:

```js
const pwDate = new Date('Thu Oct 20 2022 13:51:57 GMT+0900');
const diff = Math.floor((new Date - pwDate)/1000/60/60/24);

console.log(diff)
```